# How to seed a table with a foreign key constraint laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, faker

How can I seed my Comments table with comments.post_id as Foreign Key to post.id.

I have a Factory for the Comments table but not for the Post table.The Post table I populate manually so I can not link Factories.

I have a problem with adding a comment, because of the FK constraint. I insert a post.id manually, but don;t know how to let Laravel choose an id automatically.

Thanks in advance, Sam

**CommentFactory**

```html
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Comment;
use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;


class CommentFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Comment::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            //
            'post_id'=> 38,
            'author' => $this->faker->name(),
            'comment' => $this->faker->realText(150),
            'approved' => 0,
        ];
    }
}
```

**CommentSeeder**

```html
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use App\Models\Comment;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class CommentSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // factory(App\Comment::class, 25)->create();
        Comment::factory()->count(rand(1,5))->create(); 
    }
}
```

**Comment Model

```html
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Comment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['author','comment', 'post_id','approved'];

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }

    
}
```

**

Comment: In `CommentFactory->definition`, how about getting the list of Post IDs from the DB and pick a random one to return?

Comment: read this article: https://medium.com/@gdiasdasilva/using-faker-to-seed-data-in-php-while-respecting-foreign-key-restrictions-abad5ac1b013

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working! I used the pluck() method to create the array and the randdomElement() method to choose a random id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Post::all()->random()->id,` always fetch any random post ID and assign it the comment.

```html
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Comment;
use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;


class CommentFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Comment::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            //
            'post_id'=> Post::all()->random()->id, <---- try this.
            'author' => $this->faker->name(),
            'comment' => $this->faker->realText(150),
            'approved' => 0,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used pluck() to create an array with all post.id

```
$posts = Post::all()->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

and used randomElement() to pick a random id as a post_id

```
$post_id = $this->faker->randomElement($posts);
```

Many thanks for the suggestions!